# loop until message on page change selenium python

Tags: python, loops, selenium-chromedriver

I have a **scraper** that extract values from a page. In this site i have a button to pass to a next value and update the data on the page. When there's no more values to extract, the page shows a message in a footer. I need to repeat the cycle until the message appears.

The message have two possible values, and when the values changes to the specific message i need to go to another page and send others values.
My problem is i don´t know how to repeat the cycle until the value change because the page is updated each time i repeat the cycle or in other words the message is dynamic. When the value changes, I don't extract the values ​​and send new values ​​that I have in an excel sheet.

I try with this, but it doesn't work:

```
#with open("Output.txt", "a") as text_file:

for x in range (2,9):
    inputrut = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="BodyText"]/input[1]""")
    inputrut.clear()
    rutvalue=  ws.cell(row=x, column=1).value
    dvvalue= ws.cell(row=x, column=2).value
    inputrut.send_keys(str(rutvalue)+"-"+str(dvvalue))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MenuTable"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/input""").click()
    mensaje = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="FootText"]""").get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print (mensaje)

    if mensaje !="&nbsp;?don't have values":
        print(x)
        mensajeproximo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="FootText"]""").get_attribute("innerHTML")
        
        mensajeproximo3 = "&nbsp;?dont have more values"  
      
        while mensajeproximo != mensajeproximo3:
            
            print("next "+mensajeproximo)
            extractvalues(driver)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MenuTable"]/tbody/tr[3]/td/input""").click()
                               
        else: 
            print("new value")
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MenuTable"]/tbody/tr[3]/td/input""").click()
    
    else: 
        text_file = open("Output.txt", "a")
        text_file.write(str(rutvalue)+"-"+str(dvvalue)+"NO REGISTRA"+'\n')
        print("no values")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MenuTable"]/tbody/tr[3]/td/input""").click()
```

Where's is the problem in the cycle?

Regards

Comment: maybe inside current loop you should use `while True`- loop with code which checks elements without using `click()`

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could run and see problem. Maybe it needs only some `sleep()` so it will have time to update data. OR maybe you may need some inner loop which will repeate some code until you get message and then it will use `break` to exit this loop and go back to main `for`-loop to repeate code for new value.

Comment: @furas thank you very much for your approach!. I used the while true for the loop and added a else block with a break and "voila!". The loop is working perfect now

Answer (score 1):

here is the code for the cycle:

```
   while True:
                if driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="FootText"]""").get_attribute("innerHTML") == mensajeproximo2:
                    print("next")
                    extractvalues(driver)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MenuTable"]/tbody/tr[3]/td/input""").click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                                    
                else: 
                    message =driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="FootText"]""").get_attribute("innerHTML")
                    print("new value"+message)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="MenuTable"]/tbody/tr[3]/td/input""").click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    break
```